# Extracting inline javascript var in html source to a PHP array

Tags: javascript, php

There is some data that I need to get from a local crawled page. It's inline javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var graph_data = {"query":{"cid":["13908"],"timestamp_from":1402531200,"timestamp_till":1402531200,"views":1138942,"data":
```

etc, the variable is very long but you get the idea. I want to put "graph_data" into an array called $data. What is the best way to do this? I should add this is all being done by me locally & I don't need to execute any javascript code, just extract the data.

Comment: it's just a string. find the var line. strip off the useless bits, and boom, there you go.

Comment: if this is inserted into the dom, you already have access to graph_data globally.

Comment: Thanks just couldn't get json_decode to work.

Answer (score 0):

I have make a suggestion purely as an idea with some code worth trying!
As suggested, the DOM Document may provide this much easier, but here's another possible solution for extracting...

I'm guessing that the var graph_data is a JSON string that you want to extract from the HTML page so that you can store as a PHP var. The problem is that your code doesn't show how the variable ends but I'm going to assume that a new line break would be the way to identify the end of the variable being set. It may be a semi-colon though and if it is, instead of "\r\n" try ";"

```
// Assuming your html code is stored in $html...
preg_match("/var graph_data[^\{]*?(\{[^\r\n]+?)/is",$html,$match);
print "<pre>";
print_r($match);
print "</pre>";
```

This should result in $match[1] storing the part you need.
You can try passing that into json_decode() but that's touching some wood with crossed fingers.

Good luck...